# Google Chrome extension: chrome.history.getVisits not returning the latest visits of a url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension to list down the last visit time of a URL from the history.

The problem is, it does not return the latest visit information of a URL, whereas it shows the correct info for the same URL under 'chrome://history'.

Here is the code. I am calling this function inside $(document).ready() of the 'default_popup' html file when user clicks the extension icon to open it.

```
chrome.history.getVisits({
    "url" : 'some_url'
}, function(results) {
    for (var x = 0; x < results.length; x++) {
       console.log('--- visit time is: ' + results[x].visitTime);
    }
});
```

It lists down some old visits for this URL but not the latest ones that I visited an hour ago for example.

My Google Chrome Version is: 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit on Mac)

Comment: can you see same URL in chrome://history?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in chrome://history.

Comment: Found the answer from Chrome extension samples (also answered another similar question with the details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243622/chrome-history-getvisits-returning-empty-set-even-though-item-exists-in-chrome/39672304#39672304).